# Text floating in block next to image

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve the following placement:

Two different texts (in block) floating / inline next to image. (Everything inside div).

I have been trying with different display settings (block + inline for text etc.) but it is still not working.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="res">
<img src="<?php echo 'img/'.$row["sType"].'.png';?>"/>
<span>TITLEe</span>
<span>Description</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.res {

    height:60px;
    background-color:yellow;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    text-align:left;

}

.res img {

    margin-top:8.5px;
    margin-left:5px;
    display:inline
}

.res span {

    display:block;
}
```

Comment: What should happen if the `Element description` text extends beyond the bottom of the image element?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```css
.content {
    width: 400px;
    border: 4px solid red;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content img {
    margin-right: 15px;
    float: left;
}

.content h3,
.content p{
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <img src="http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/socialmediaicons_v120/48/google.png"/ alt="" >
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Some Description</p>
</div>​
```

Comment: Super helpful and super simple. My feeble brain kept wanting to float the *text* left, not the image. This simple example was a forehead-slapper! *Of course* the image should receive the float, not the text! Thank you for this elegant response.

Answer (score 3):

Hi why used to float left you can do this without used `float` as like this

```
<div class="res">
<img src="<?php echo 'img/'.$row["sType"].'.png';?>"/>
<div class="text"><h5>TITLEe</h5>
  <p>Description</p></div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
    .res {
    height:60px;
    background-color:yellow;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
img, .text{
vertical-align:top;
}
.text{
display:inline-block;
}
p, h5{
margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

and change to css, class according to your design

Answer (score 2):

well you can try the classic way using tables although it is not recommended to use tables for layout

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><img src="yourimage" /> </th>
    <th >adsasd<br/>adas</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please do not use tables to style.

Answer (score 1):

try this.....should work

html:

```
<div id="testDiv">
    <div class="imgContainer"><img src="path/image.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="textContainer"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#testDiv { float:left; width: 360px; }
#testDiv .imgContainer { float:left; width:120px; height:90px; }
#testDiv .textContainer { float:left; width:240px; height:90px; overflow:hidden }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="img.jpg" class='left;' />
  <h1 class='right'>TITLE</h1>
  <div class='right'>Element description</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap { width: 600px; /* Just a sample value */ }
.left { width: 200px; float: left; }
.right { margin-left: 220px; width: 380px;}
```

That should do the trick.
Adjust width and margin params to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
margin-top: 30px;
```

to your text. That makes it 30 pixels lower. simple

Comment: This will not create the desired effect at all. The accepted answer is an appropriate solution. If you feel like you can offer a more efficient way, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).